# Why volatile is not working properly

Tags: java, multithreading, static, volatile

Today I was creating one timeout job using `TimerTask` but fell in to a new problem where i have a `static volatile boolean` variable  `flag`. My understanding is as soon as value of this variable get changed it is notified by all running `thread`. But when I ran this program I got below output which is not acceptable.

**O/P:**

```
--------------
--------------
DD
BB
Exiting process..
CC
```

My expectation is my last print should be **Exiting process..** Why is this strange behavior?

My code is:

```
public class TimeOutSort {

    static volatile boolean flag = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                flag = true;
                System.out.println("Exiting process..");
                // System.exit(0);
            }
        }, 10 * 200);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (!flag)
                    System.out.println("BB");

            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (!flag)
                    System.out.println("CC");

            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (!flag)
                    System.out.println("DD");

            }
        }).start();
    }

}
```

**Edit:** How can i achieve this ?

Comment: Because thread execution sequence is not guranteed!!

Comment: Are you saying that `volatile` is not working or you are not using it correctly? ;)

Comment: I am not talking about sequencing , am just curious as soon my flag become true why statement in while loop is getting executed?

Comment: @PeterLawrey , May be , I am able to figure out what is the problem

Comment: You shouldn't really modify the substance of your question after it's been answered in an edit. You asked for an explanation you observed the behaviour you observed and you got perfectly good answers to that; it's unfair to move the goalpost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`volatile` pretty much means that each time a thread accesses a variable it must ensure to use the version visible to each thread (i.e. no per-thread caching).

This **doesn't** force the CC-printing thread to actually get to run *immediately* after the `flag` has been set to `true`. It's entirely possible (especially on a single-core machine) that one thread sets the flag *and* prints the message *before* the CC-printing thread even had a chance to run.

Also: note that printing to `System.out` involves acquiring a lock (somewhere inside the `println()` call), which can *modify* the multi-threaded behaviour of test code.

Answer (score 3):

Threads can execute code in any order

```
thread BB: while (!flag) // as flag is false
thread Main:   flag = true;
thread Main:   System.out.println("Exiting process..");
thread BB:     System.out.println("BB");
```

> My expectation is my last print should be Exiting process..

Threads are designed to run concurrently and independently. It would be surprising if this was always the last statement because you can't be sure where each thread is when you set the flag.

Comment: @amicngh Proper synchronisation. In this case, having the `TimerTask` wait until the others are done using [`join()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()). I'd recommend hitting [an operating systems textbook](http://www.williamstallings.com/OS4e.html) as well, that's where this subject matter tends to be covered.

Comment: But then they will execute in sequence .

Comment: @amicngh Huh? No, I meant synchronisation in the general sense of "knowing what the heck you're doing when using threads", not the sense of "mutual exclusion" that Java's choice of keyword for this implies.

Answer (score 1):

The thread that prints "CC" happened not to receive any CPU time until after your thread that prints "Exiting process..." printed that. This is expected behavior.

Comment: How can i achieve this behavior ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not volatile not working (if it were not, some of your threads would not have stopped). It's about the order of execution of instructions in the different threads, and this is random (depends on OS scheduling) unless you explicitly synchronize the loops at intermediate steps.

Comment: Randomness still exists irrespective of synchronization. Synchronization guarantees single thread at a time, but doesn't guarantee thread A executes first then thread B etc.,

Comment: @thinksteep I meant "synchronization" in the general sense - using latches, barriers or any other mechanism which allows one thread to control the execution of another, not simple mutual exclusion (usage of "synchronized" block inside the loop), which as you correctly point out wouldn't solve the ordering issue here.

Answer (score 1):

To add an alternative phrasing to the explanations you got: in your sample output, the thread that prints `"CC"` got suspended (somewhere) "*between*" the lines `while (!flag)` and `System.out.println()`. Which means that after it wakes up, the `println()` executes *before* the next check of the flag. (It also won't get woken up just because you change the flag value, but because some other thread blocks or uses up its time slice.)

Answer (score 0):

i didn't test it , but you may achieve it like this

```
public class TimeOutSort {

static volatile boolean flag = false;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            synchronized(flag){
                 flag = true;
                 notifyAll();
            }


        }
    }, 10 * 200);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            synchronized(flag){
                if(!flag)
                {
                    wait();
                }
                System.out.println("BB");

            }


        }
    }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

              synchronized(flag){
                if(!flag)
                {
                    wait();
                }
                System.out.println("CC");

            }
        }
    }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

              synchronized(flag){
                if(!flag)
                {
                    wait();
                }
                System.out.println("DD");

            }


        }
    }).start();
}
```

}